# Regular Expression for Not Matching Exact Words

Tags: .net, regex

I would like my reg ex to accept characters in the set [a-zA-Z0-9.\?!%, ] and also not except the exact words "not set".

Examples of successful matches:

```
category1
myCategory
Hello World!!!
notset
```

Examples of unsuccessful matches:

```
{empty string}
not set
Not Set
NOT SET
<script>
```

I am using the .NET framework.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you throw in a `<script>` tag, trying to parse html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
^(?![nN][oO][tT] [sS][eE][tT]$)[a-zA-Z0-9.?!%, ]+$
```

When using (?i:) in my .net validators and unobtrusive javascript I noticed my client side validation was getting disabled.

Answer (score 9):

Obviosly, you can test for "not set" by code. If it has to be a regex, you can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!not set$)[a-zA-Z0-9.?!%, ]+$
```

[Working Example](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=ca99fbc3-3c13-4c47-8f49-75dd9b3ee562)

A C# code example would be:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"^(?!not set$)[a-zA-Z0-9.?!%, ]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
{
    // all is well
}
```

If you want the match to be case insensitive (that is "Not Set" is invalid, but "not set" is valid), use:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"^(?!Not Set$)[a-zA-Z0-9.?!%, ]+$");
```

Comment: Missing a note about case-sensitivity... but +1 (even if I would format it a tad different ;-)

Comment: This will match `5Q not set TR` .

Comment: @sln - that is left for interpretation. "5Q not set TR" is not *"the exact words **"not set"**"*, and the examples do not address it. Either way, you can easily change it to `^(?!.*\bnot set\b)[a-zA-Z0-9.?!%, ]+$`

Comment: @sln - "5Q not set TR" is allowed. The only thing is case sensitivity because this matches "Not Set".

Comment: @Kobi - how can  I make this case sensitive?

Comment: @Bob - I've updated the answer with both options, let me know if you're having more trouble with it.

Comment: @Kobi - I'd prefer to use a one-liner that I can plug into my .NET regular expression validator on the aspx page. Is this possible?

Comment: @bob - the easiest thing is to have multiple validators. You can set can insensitivity inline using `(?i)`, but I don't think it works on a regex validator (I think that one is using JavaScript, I should test how it works)

Comment: @Kobi - I plugged this into my validator and it works. However, I am using unobtrusive client side validation and I find that any regular expression with ?i: causes the client side validation to disable and use the server side validation instead. I no longer get the error message when tabbing off the input box, only when I post back to the server. Weird behaviour!

Comment: I ended up using ^(?![nN][oO][tT] [sS][eE][tT]$)[a-zA-Z0-9.?!%, ]+$. This did not disable my client side validation.

Answer (score 2):

This might work `^(?i:(?!not set)[a-z0-9.\\?!%, ])+$`  (untested)

**EDIT**
`Didn't work for me. – Bob 4 hours ago`

@Bob - Here are *your* samples.

Examples of successful matches:

```
category1
myCategory
Hello World!!!
notset
```

Examples of unsuccessful matches:

```
{empty string}
not set
Not Set
NOT SET
<script>
```

What didn't work?

```
@samples = (
 'category1',
 'myCategory',
 'Hello World!!!',
 'notset',
 '',
 'not set',
 'Not Set',
 'NOT SET',
 '<script>'
);

for (@samples) {
   print "'$_'";
   if (/^(?i:(?!not set)[a-z0-9.\\?!%, ])+$/) {
      print " - yes matches\n";
   }
   else {
      print " - no\n";
   }
}
```

output:

'`category1`' - yes matches
'`myCategory`' - yes matches
'`Hello World!!!`' - yes matches
'`notset`' - yes matches
'' - no
'`not set`' - no
'`Not Set`' - no
'`NOT SET`' - no
'`<script>`' - no

Comment: I tried online regular expression testers like http://regexpal.com/ and http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html, it did not work.

Comment: Let me try it in my actual application, maybe these online testers are not build for case sensitivity. I'll let you know.

Comment: I plugged this into my validator and it works. However, I am using unobtrusive client side validation and I find that any regular expression with ?i: causes the client side validation to disable and use the server side validation instead. I no longer get the error message when tabbing off the input box, only when I post back to the server. Weird behaviour!

Comment: I ended up using ^(?![nN][oO][tT] [sS][eE][tT]$)[a-zA-Z0-9.?!%, ]+$. This did not disable my client side validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "NOT SET";

    if (str.ToLower().Equals("not set"))
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    else
    {
        String pattern = @"^[a-z0-9.\?!%,]+$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (regex.IsMatch(str))
        {
            // Do Something
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer a one liner regular expression that I can plug into my validator.